# Reassemble images forwarded though Linux router?

Tags: images, network-monitor, http

In 2003-2004 I used a Linux app that **reassembled images from HTTP traffic** forwarded through a Linux router, displaying them live. Just a command line app that threw up an X window, showing the images as they were pulled down.

I'm trying to find the app now - **what was the app called?**

Answer (score 2):

Got it: the software was called [Driftnet](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~chris/driftnet/)